# Twilio's statuses and events

Tags: java, scala, twilio, twilio-api

im using Scala with Twilio's java SDK

i am sending a voice a message and configured the current events to get webhook responses for all values in the enum Number.Event

(this is directly from Twilio's SDK)

```
public class Number extends TwiML {
    public enum Event {
        INITIATED("initiated"),
        RINGING("ringing"),
        ANSWERED("answered"),
        COMPLETED("completed");
```

after i make the async call, i can get the status of the call which is a different enum

(this is directly from Twilio's SDK)

```
public enum Status {
        QUEUED("queued"),
        RINGING("ringing"),
        IN_PROGRESS("in-progress"),
        COMPLETED("completed"),
        BUSY("busy"),
        FAILED("failed"),
        NO_ANSWER("no-answer"),
        CANCELED("canceled");
```

i ran the code, sent a voice message , answered it, and let Twilio hang up.

now, im looking at twilio's monitor -> logs -> calls.

i can see that when i initiated the request , i got field status: **queued**

afterwards, i am seeing multilpe webhook request with the field CallStatus:
**initiated**,
**ringing**,
**in-progress**,
**completed**

1. Can i only subscribe to these 4 events; **initiated, ringing, answered, completed**?
2. I dont understand what are the CallStatuses values i can get
   for example, initiated is defined in Event while in-progress is defined in Status

[twilio monitor log calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnHYl.png)
you can see two post methods, the first one is collapsed. this is me sending the request to twilio

the second one is twilio sending me a webhook update

**the CallStatus is "initiated".it is not on the list you provided**

why is it not on the list? are there any more ones that are not listed?

Edit: formatting
added a screenshot from twilio's console

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Scala. However, you can subscribe to events as explained in the [StatusCallbackEvent](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallbackevent) documentation:

> If you specify any call progress events in the StatusCallbackEvent
> parameter, Twilio will make an asynchronous request to the
> StatusCallback URL you provided in your POST request.
>
> The call progress events you can specify are:
>
> initiated - Twilio removes your call from the queue and starts dialing.
>
> ringing - The call starts ringing.
>
> answered - The call is answered. If this event is specified, Twilio will send an in-progress status.
>
> completed - The call is completed, regardless of the termination status (which can be busy, cancelled, completed, failed, or no-answer).

Here is the code from the Twilio docs showing [how to set the status callback events in Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-call-resource-and-specify-a-statuscallbackevent&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=9.x):

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.http.HttpMethod;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example {
    // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Call call = Call.creator(
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+14155551212"),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+18668675310"),
                URI.create("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"))
            .setMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .setStatusCallback(URI.create("https://www.myapp.com/events"))
            .setStatusCallbackEvent(
                Arrays.asList("initiated",
                "answered"))
            .setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .create();

        System.out.println(call.getSid());
    }
}
```

If you use the above, the "https://www.myapp.com/events" endpoint (which you will need to customize the url and host yourself) will receive webhooks as the call progresses through the various states.

Also, webhook events (initiated, ringing, answered, completed) can be thought of state change messages. Call status are similar but reflect the current state at the moment in time you use the REST API to check the call status. Queued means Twilio is waiting to make the outbound call.

[Edited to include the list of call status values]

The list of [Call Status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-status-values) values from the [Call Resource Reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource):

```
Status - Description
queued - The call is ready and waiting in line before dialing.
ringing - The call is currently ringing.
in-progress - The call was answered and is currently in progress.
canceled - The call was hung up while it was queued or ringing.
completed - The call was answered and has ended normally.
busy - The caller received a busy signal.
no-answer - There was no answer or the call was rejected.
failed - The call could not be completed as dialed, most likely because the phone number was non-existent.
```

This "[Timeline of an Outbound Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#get-call-status-events-during-a-call)" diagram helps illustrate the connection between webhook events and call status:
[image]

To answer the new additional questions, I have not come across a Twilio status or webhook event that was not listed somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: My code is working, i used the documentation you linked. i am asking about the Type of the field CallStatus that i get from the Twilio's webhook response, and its expected values. it seems to be an amalgamation of the two Enums i wrote.

Comment: @urield, super! Since the answer was helpful please accept it. In terms of what values are returned, the Twilio docs are spread out over several pages. I also keep my own list and use both ngrok and the Twilio Console to view the web requests being sent - this helps troubleshoot my local parsing. To be clear, the type that Twilio is returning is a string. Casting it to an enum is up to you. Queued is a call state and not a webhook hook event. You won't get a webhook event for "dialed" because you don't really need it - you already know when you dialed the call because your code did it.

Comment: you answered my first question, there are only 4 event I can subscribe to, the ones that I have mentioned. But I still don't understand what is the answer to my second question. What are all of the possible values that can be returned under CallStatus?

Comment: I edited the answer. They are listed in the Twilio docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-status-values)

Comment: added a screen shot to the initial question, where you can see i got a call status which is not written in the documentation (or in the list you provided)

Comment: Initiated is a webhook event. Maybe you are hungup (see the pun?) that it is labelled CallStatus and not CallEvent? Your screenshot appears to be from the webhook event - it is what triggered the webhook. I've found this "Timeline of a call" diagram helpful: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#get-call-status-events-during-a-call

Comment: The first post request is me sending the request to Twilio, hence the URL starts with api.twilio . the second post request is Twilio sending me a status update event, not the other way around . this is why the "direction" field says it is a "outbound-api" and the "callbackSource is "call-progress-event". as i mentioned, i got multiple  responses, the one i sent in the picture and the rest have identical fields.

Comment: direction: outbound-api means you are making an outbound voicecall (i.e. you are calling someone). Twilio will send 1 webhook for each call status change that you have subscribed to. Your webhook endpoint is returning 503 (server not ready) so it could be that Twilio is retrying the request which is why you are receiving duplicate requests to your webhook endpoint. My experience is that Twilio will not retry failed requests but I haven't tried returning a 503. I primarily use the Twilio console for troubleshooting and view the webhook events on my local server receiving the request.

Comment: my server is returning 503 because i have not implemented a correct response yet. because i am having an issue trying to find out what the possible statuses i receive. each response has a different status, as i said in the begging of my question. i just dont understand why i get the "initiated" status if it is not a viable Call Status

Comment: You haven't received an initiated call status - you have received an initiated call event. This is confirmed because the endpoint is your server's url and the CallbackSource is listed as call-progress-events.

Comment: why are you saying it is not a call status? it says "CallStatus" : "initiated". why are you referring to it as call event? i thought call event is what you can subscribe to when sending the voice message. CallStatus is updates you get from Twilio as the phone call changes its status

Comment: I am not sure what additional you are seeking and unfortunately cannot offer assist further other than what is in my answer and these comments.